# Mass delete unpopular Tags

Tags: wordpress, tags, sql-delete

Mass delete unpopular Tags

I have 1000's of tags and I would like to simply delete all tags that aren't used more than X times... i.e. 5 times.

Does anyone know of a simple way to do this? Even straight SQL would totally ROCK!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$x = 5; // set this to any number
$sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `wp_terms`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $count[$name]++;
}
foreach($count as $key = $value)
{
  if($value < $x)
    {
      $sql2 = "DELETE FROM `wp_terms` WHERE `name` = '". $key ."'";
      $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    }
}
```

There's more efficient ways of doing it but this will do the job.

Edit: make a backup first. I'm not entirely sure that that table is exclusive to tags.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot for the super fast responses... I'll give them a try now. Thanks again

Comment: I think you'll want to use Jason McCreary's example to alter my code (or just run the queries and see what happens). It looks like you need to delete the rows in three layers instead of just from one database.

Comment: you can delete from just `wp_terms`, but you'll have poor data integrity and problems if you added another tag with the same name.

Answer (score 3):

Doing with with an SQL command is going to be your best bet. The tables `wp_terms`, `wp_term_relationships`, and `wp_term_taxonomy` are the ones of interest. WordPress keeps track of relationships with `wp_term_taxonomy.count`. So this help make life easier.

```
-- remove terms
DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'tag' AND count <= 5;)
-- remove all relationships
DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'tag' AND count <= 5;)
-- remove taxonomy entry
DELETE FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'tag' AND count <= 5;
```

**Note:** I would strongly suggest making a backup of these tables before running the commands above.

Comment: @Riccardo. It should as I am not aware of any schema changes in 3.1.3. Either way note my **Note**. :)

Comment: Yes, I have performed a backup and started cleaning up. 38,000 tags wiped away! Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, I see Kolchy's comment below. I had to change 'tag' to 'post_tag'

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to back up the database first

```
DELETE a,c FROM wp_terms AS a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS c ON a.term_id = c.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS b on b.term_taxonomy_id = c.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE ( c.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND c.count <= 5 );
```

On the last line, you could also modify `c.count <= 5` and replace 5 with any number of your choice.

Comment: This SQL is great, but I'm curious why you wouldn't also delete the rows in `wp_term_relationships` (table `b`) ?

Answer (score 0):

Jasons answer worked except in my install, the name of the taxonomy was 'post_tag' not 'tag'

Comment: It's best practice to comment on the answer and upvote if it worked for you as opposed to supplying a separate answer.