# Deleting latest Wordpress tags from database

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, tags

I need your help regarding Wordpress mySQL query.

**Situation**

I am using WordPress 3.0.1, installed one "Clever plugin" that automatically tagged my posts with tags. By mistake i marked that this plugin can tag also "related posts". So in the end this plugin not only created good and relevant tags to the posts I need, but also created a lot of trash tags to **un**related posts.

What I have now - lots of tags in the database and panels which really need to be deleted. I can find in database FROM WHAT TAG ID I want to delete (wp_terms table, term_id field) those tags.

**More**

I have access to phpMyAdmin, also I know that I need to delete records using SQL query from tables

> wp_terms , wp_term_relationships, and wp_term_taxonomy

Also there was quite issue like mine here [Mass delete unpopular Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539954/wordpress-mass-delete-unpopular-tags)

**Help!**

Maybe someone who is familiar with wordpress can help help me and write query to remove tags and all needed relations from certain term_id and until end?

Comment: is emptying the table an option??

Answer (score 1):

Since term_id is incremented automatically, you can probably DELETE all records WHERE term_id is greater than the term ID of the tags you want to keep.

```
DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id >= [ID] );

DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy);
```

Replace [ID] with the first term ID you want to delete.

Comment: Well i thought about this simple deletion in wp_terms table, but anyway there will be relations in wp_term_relationships, and wp_term_taxonomy left to empty terms... So issue is more complex - i need to delete terms and also all relations to them in database to keep it consistent.

Comment: Yeah, so those tables are all related. You simply delete the records in wp_term_relationships that not longer associate with terms that exist in wp_terms and wp_term_taxonomy. I edited my post to show you the code that I think will work. I can confirm when I get home. Please backup your database.

Comment: Thanks, i will try doing this one later today.

Answer (score 1):

Corey, thanks for help, can you imagine... i only now got back to this issue...

And one more update, maybe it will save some time for someone. If you want to mass delete tags from Wordpress database (mySQL query in phpmyadmin) between some ID's, you can execute almost same SQL query:

```
DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id >= [FromID] AND term_id <= [ToID] );

DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy);
```

Just replace [FromID] with starting ID of tag you want to delete, and [ToID] with ending tad to delete.

So if you need to remove tags from lets say from ID 231 until ID 1098, final query looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id >= 231 AND term_id <= 1098 );

DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy);
```

Live long, and prosper!